# How to remove or hide a div(or div class) but not its content with twitter-bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is an easy question. But what I want to know is: Is there a way to delete a div without removing its content USING bootstrap? I can also refactor the question to: Is there a way to delete a div CLASS dynamically with Bootstrap?

My code is simple:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         GOOGLE MAP
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I know there already exists a way to make it visible and or hide it (hidden-phone ..), but what I want to do is actually remove the container, the row and the cols and leave the google map to fill the whole width.

What I have right now is:

```
<div class="container hidden-phone">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <div class="googleMap"> ... </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And then, right after that, I add the div of the google map again. But instead of hidden-phone, now:

```
<div class="googleMap visible-phone"> ... </div>
```

This way, when you switch to a phone, the container and separations of the map with the screen are none.

This is the easiest way, but it seems a little unpractical, because maybe I don't see one, but it is there, so I'm downloading the map into the client twice, I believe that is not clever.

I could always use JavaScript(jQuery) to listen to the event of resizing and remove it my self.. That is not a problem at all, but maybe bootstrap has a build-in functionality already, something like a data attribute like "data-hidden-phone-class='someClass'", or maybe a class that hides some classes when resizing like: "hidden-classes-phone" this way when the screen resizes to a phone one, boostrap would hide all the classes of that element? Or something.

I know the names for attributes and classes are not attractive, but is for the purpose of the question.

I hope I made myself clear enough, let me know if you don't understand something, thanks!

Comment: just to make it clear, most data-enabled functions ( if not all ) use javascript anyways, bootstrap can't modify the dom by it self, you need javascript if that's what you want.

Comment: Honest question: @Mohammad then why do they have a cdn for their scripts? like: `<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It's your choice to use the CDN or not, CDN kinda lessens the load on your server and provides good response time and download speeds. I don't really understand the point of the question.

Comment: It is okay, I guess they do not have that functionality, I just didn't want to code it without knowing, and I realize something. I could use Less to create a custom container (mixin) of their container which I can media query like: `@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .container-sm {
    .container
  }
}` Something like that.